# Find and count duplicates

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I need count duplicates in col 'C' when col 'A' or 'B' is greater than 0 or equal 0?

```
 A  B  C
 1  0  500
 0  1  500
 0  0  500
 1  1  500
 1  1  300
 1  0  300
 0  1  300
 0  0  300
```

I get so far

'A' and 'B' greater than 0

```
df[(df['A'] > 0) & (df['B'] > 0)].groupby('C').size()

 500 1
 300 1
```

'A' or 'B' greater than 0 or equal 0

```
df[(df['A'] == 0) | (df['B'] == 0)].groupby('C').size()

 500 3
 300 3
```

How I can print this in one DataFrame?

Expected Output

```
 500 1 3
 300 1 3
```

Comment: I don't get the second desired output. There are no rows in your dataframe where A und B are both zero.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English 'A' or 'B' is equal to 0, so 'A' is 0 and 'B' is 1, second  'B' is 1 and 'A' is 0.

Comment: I have edited a description of the question.

Comment: It's still unclear. A and B are only greater than 0 in the rows `1  1  500` and `1  1  300`. So there are zero duplicates in C with respect to these rows, yet you count one duplicate for 500 and one duplicate for 300 in your expected result.

Comment: Yes, in this sample there is zero duplicate, but I need to count how many times, the duplicated number from column 'C' (500) is in "A and B are greater than 0", so output must show me 500 1.

Answer (score 0):

You might as well pre-compute `A | B` and `A & B` unless space is an issue. Then, you can use:

```
df["AND"] = df.A & df.B
df["OR"] = df.A | df.B

res = df.groupby("C")[["AND", "OR"]].agg("sum")
```

Resulting in:

```
     AND  OR
C
300    1   3
500    1   3
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try to check it.